# Looking for an open database of individual human whole-head structural magnetic resonance images

Tags: medical

I'm looking for an open data source with single-patient human whole-head structural magnetic resonance images, preferably in NIfTI format. Healthy adults, high SNR and citeable source would be pluses.

Problem that I'm facing now is that it seems that most of the available MRIs are either cut, so that only brain is visible or require jumping through a whole bunch of hoops before they allow access.

Comment: How much whole your whole-head images should be? they are usually cut for anonymity and therefore ethical reasons, so you might have a problem if you are interested in face mri or something like that

Comment: @user2173836 Well, whole head above neck is needed, including the face. MRIs are needed for volume conduction modelling for some EEG analyses, where (virtual) electrodes will potentially be placed even close to the face. The mode we're using is quite problematic when cuts are encountered, however it provides very good results without cuts.

Comment: In that case I don't think you will be able to get such data without the 'hoops.' You have to promise your subjects that the data you share will be anonymized, so no face. All labs have the data, but they won't be downloadable from some website. At least I am not aware of such dataset